# Android SQLite delete issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to using SQLite with android and I am having been struggling with what I think is a pretty simple design issue.

I have a table that holds rows of data, the first item being the id that is AUTOINCREMENTED. My arrayadapter that displays the DB has a click method that looks like this: (which passes the id to the next activity)

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), InstanceView.class);
            i.putExtra("InstanceSelected",(int)id);
            startActivity(i);   
        }
```

So the id in the array adapter is used in the next activity to display more info about the row of data. My issue comes when I delete. Once I delete one of the rows in the table, the indexing from the table to the array adapter is no longer correct.

My DB:

```
String CREATE_SAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE sat ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " + 
            "name TEXT, "+
            "userid INTEGER")
```

My question is:

What would be a better way to do this. I need to be able to display a SQLite table in an array adapter and be able to access the correct row by clicking the adapter. Given that the id's of the table and the array adapter do not match.

Comment: 1) If ID is long, why are you truncating it to `int` in the Intent? This will make the value change. 2) I don't understand what you mean by *"Ids are no longer 0 based"* 3) Define *"no longer works"*.

Comment: do you mean that the rowid for table is not auto assigned? Like if you delete second row, the third row doesnt automatically become second. Is that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I don't think casting it as an int is an issue. It breaks with just 3 entries in the table. 

My question is how do I fill up an arrayadapter from a SQL table that does not have sequential row id's and access the data when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing there are more than one columns in the table, what you could do is pass any other value in int.putExtras(). If you have a table with columns id,name and dob then you could simply pass on the name instead of row. If there is an issue of multiple names being the same then you could ask for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a POJO for your row model?

Based on your table:

```
//use getters and setters instead
public class Sat {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public int userId;

   @Override
   public String toString() { return this.name; } //ListView/GridView item text
}
```

Now read from the database all the table rows filling a `List<Sat>`.
Then you can use an `ArrayAdapter<Sat>` and whenever you need to get one specific item using their position you can do:

```
Sat item = adapter.getItem(position);
int id = item.id;
```